# Записать переменную из синглетона в Firebase

Tags: android, firebase, singleton

Есть программа, где я могу изменять переменную с помощью синглетона. Создал 2 активити, где пользователи могут изменить эту переменную. Как записать переменную, которую изменяют, в базу Firebase. Пытался использовать метод addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener().

[image]

главный класс

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
private BubbleWrap bubbleWrap;
FirebaseDatabase database=FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
private  TextView 
final DatabaseReference AllFacebase =database.getReference("всего").child("йй");
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
     txt=findViewById(R.id.textView);
    bubbleWrap=BubbleWrap.getInstance();
    setupAddMoreButton();
    setupPopActivityButton();
    setupCocActivityButton();
    setupupdateBase();


}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    updateUI();

}
private void setupAddMoreButton(){
    Button btn=findViewById(R.id.button);
    btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            bubbleWrap.addMoreBubbles();
            updateUI();

        }
    });
}
private  void setupPopActivityButton(){
  Button btn=findViewById(R.id.button2);
  btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
      @Override
      public void onClick(View v) {
          Intent intent=new Intent(MainActivity.this,PopActivity.class);
          startActivity(intent);
      }
  });
}
private  void setupCocActivityButton(){
    Button btn=findViewById(R.id.buttoncoc);
    btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent=new Intent(MainActivity.this,CocActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
}
private void updateUI(){

    txt.setText(String.format(Locale.getDefault(),
            "%d bubbles left!",
            bubbleWrap.getNumBubbles()));
}
private void setupupdateBase(){
    AllFacebase.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {

        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {


            txt.setText(String.format(Locale.getDefault(),
                    "%d bubbles left!",
                    bubbleWrap.getNumBubbles()));
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
}
```

}

Активити, где я изменяю переменную, которую хочу записать в Firebase

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
public class PopActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
private BubbleWrap bubbleWrap;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_pop);
    bubbleWrap=BubbleWrap.getInstance();
    setupPopButton();
    updateUI();
}
private void setupPopButton(){
    Button btn=findViewById(R.id.cocbtb);
    btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            bubbleWrap.popBubble();
            updateUI();
        }
    });
}
private void updateUI(){
    TextView txt=findViewById(R.id.textView2);
    txt.setText(String.format(Locale.getDefault(),
            "Bubbles left: %d",
            bubbleWrap.getNumBubbles()));
}
```

}

Синглетон

```
public class BubbleWrap {
private static final int ADD_MORE_BUBBLES = 10;
private int numBubbles;
private static BubbleWrap instance;
private BubbleWrap(){

}
public static BubbleWrap getInstance(){
    if(instance==null){
        instance=new BubbleWrap();
    }
     return instance;
}

public int getNumBubbles() {
    return numBubbles;
}
public  void addMoreBubbles(){
    numBubbles+=ADD_MORE_BUBBLES;
}

public void popBubble() {
    numBubbles--;
}
```